# Transferring binary data from mobile app (in Swift) to server

Tags: swift, server, binary, protocol-buffers, binary-data

A third-party company is dealing with a mobile app that is getting a stream of binary data (protobuf) from physiological sensors on our device and is expected to send the binary data to a server, so it can be ingested and processed within GCP.

The third party, who wrote the mobile app in Swift claims that they don't think they can transfer the binary data per se, but that Swift requires to first base64 string encode the binary data and then decode it.

That solution would probably mess up the concatenation of multiple messages (protobuf) as we've defined it.

Any opinion on whether it is possible to send binary data (stream or flat file) directly to a backend from a mobile app written in Swift?

Thanks a lot for your insights

Comment: Did you or your third party check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732927/swift-sending-binary-file-to-a-server-convert-to-string-request) ?

Comment: It is possible to send binary data (from block or stream). Swift also can work with protobuf (needs additional package). There might just be some other constraint that's not being communicated.